# How to change max upload size for Drupal CKEditor module w/ CKFinder?

Tags: php, drupal, upload, ckeditor, ckfinder

All uploads made through CKEditor in CKFinder return the message *"Invalid file. The file size is too big."* when they exceed a certain size, even though I have defined the maximum size to 10MB every place I can think of.

**/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckfinder/config.php**
Every resource type has their maxSize var set to 15728640 bytes.
e.g.

```
$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
        'name' => 'Files',              // Single quotes not allowed
        'url' => $baseUrl . 'files',
        'directory' => $baseDir . 'files',
        'maxSize' => '10M',
        'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
        'deniedExtensions' => '');
```

I found a maxSize var in /sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckfinder/plugins/fileeditor/plugin.js as well which I have modified, no luck.

phpinfo() shows the following relevant settings:
**post_max_size:** 20M
**upload_max_filesize:** 10M

Both of which should be fine for 10MB uploads.

What else can I change to fix this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this was a problem with my hosting settings. In an act of desperation, I e-mailed the web host for ideas, and although my phpinfo() was reporting those variables correctly, they told me this:

> You were having issues earlier because
>   you had not set the suPHP
>   configuration path in the .htaccess
>   file. We have now added the suPHP path
>   to the .htaccess file.

I don't quite understand, but now it works, it was nothing to change in the Drupal setup itself. Thanks for the help everyone. (for reference, this is with http://canadianwebhosting.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at: admin/settings/uploads ? There're some max file size settings there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Though I should have mentioned I tried this as well, also set to 10MB. In fact, the Upload module wasn't even enabled at first, yet smaller uploads through CKEditor still worked. I think it's totally separate from the Upload module.

Comment: Just wondering what happens if you temporarily try using IMCE instead of CKFinder. May help you work out if the error is specific to CKFinder or a more general thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe if the file size is just a teeeny weeeeny bit more of 10mb and you havent noticed it, thats why it gets flagged down.  Try increasing the settings of
post_max_size: 12M
upload_max_filesize: 12M

also note that if  upload_max_filesize  < post_max_size , then max file size for upload is the one specified by upload_max_filesize

if upload_max_filesize > post_max_size , then max file size for upload is the one specified by post_max_size.